# Text Input Types with Gravityforms

Tags: wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin, input-type-file

I currently build a complex form with gravityforms. What i need is an area where i have some text and in between the text are some input-fields to complete the text paragraph. 
EXAMPLE.

I,***"name-inputfield"*__*_*_**, agree to be available between_***_***"text-inputfield"***_*_** and ***_*__*_***.

I already created that in a html editor and placed the code into a HTML Box of Gravityforms but if submit the information are not delivered. I believe i forget something inside the formcode.
I attached the code below

```
    I, <input type="text" name="" value="NAME"  size="40">(for myself and my heirs and legal representatives) of<br>
<input type="text" name="" value="STREET ADDRESS" size="40"><input type="text" name="" value="CITY" size="20" maxlength="20"><input type="text" name="a78" value="ST"  size="2" maxlength="2"><input type="text" name="" value="ZIP"  size="10" maxlength="10"><br>
hereby release Blanca's house Corp., its agents, representatives, directors, employees, contractors, insurers, and members from any and all responsibility and liability involving arising out of, or related to the planned medical mission scheduled to <span class=""><input type="text" name=" " value="" size="20" maxlength="20">starting on <input type="text" name="" value="" size="20" maxlength="20"> through <input type="text" name="" value=""  size="20" maxlength="20"> 20<input type="text" name="" value="" size="2" maxlength="2">, including (without limitation) liability regarding my health or safety or my personal property.
```

Would be great if anybody could help me, because i never did something like this. 
Here is also a screenshot of how it looks inside the browser http://awesomescreenshot.com/01e2la0ibc 
Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 2):

Inputs inside the content of the HTML field will not be captured by Gravity Forms. They aren't "registered" by Gravity Forms so it doesn't know they exist.

There are two alternatives for what you are trying to accomplish.

1. You can add the fields via Gravity Forms and then style them to be inline. Here is a great example of how this can be accomplished:
   http://www.rocketgenius.com/gravity-forms-mad-lib-style-form-demo/
2. You can add the fields via Gravity Forms and then output the submitted values in an HTML field on a second page. Here is a example of this using my product [GP Preview Submission](http://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gp-preview-submission/):
    http://demos.gravitywiz.com/gp-preview-submission/

Comment: OMG.... THIS http://www.rocketgenius.com/gravity-forms-mad-lib-style-form-demo/ saved my live... well, you did it by providing it! i was so desperated trying... thank you so much... I only have one issue. I can create those fields inside the form but the css he provided is not matching the website style and i dont know how i could do it myself... i dont even know where to add that custom css in gravityforms... can you help me on that?

Comment: Styles are best placed in your theme's _style.css_ file. As far as adjusting the style of the mad lib form to match your theme's look and feel, you might consider hiring a front-end developer to help with that. The alternative is taking some time to learn CSS. I think you could probably make most of the changes you needed to without having to sink too much time into mastering CSS. :)

Comment: thanks a lot, well, i know a lot on css.. and finally i was also able to do it... the problem is just, that even fields without the class of that mad lib now are affected and dont behave as they should... is there a way to bypass that? i was forced to give the whole form wrapper that mabstyle class but only certain fields are conected to that css... how can i avoid other fields to be affected by the mab lib style class?